# I want to generate token(customer ID) with a Letter for identify customers

Tags: vb.net, token

I want to generate token(customer ID) with a Letter for identify customers.
Example- D0101

In my program customers should be navigated into correct department ,
therefore we should generate unique id for each customer and print it on a leaflet with more information .

I just need to generate token/customer id (with one letter) for each customer due to the department.

Example -

Development Department  - A102,
Social Department      -  D012,
Land and permit dept   -  E210

I tried some code :

```
Dim autonum as integer = 101

txtautonum.text = autonum

  If inc <> MaxRows - 1 Then
        inc = MaxRows - 1

        autonum = ds.Tables("ForRepair").Rows(inc).Item(4)
        'txtRepID.Text = autonum + 1

    End If
 If autonum - autonum2 < 0 And autonum2 - autonum > 0 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("autonum2 is bigger")
        txtRepID.Text = autonum+ 1

End If
```

This code only increments a previously stored number. i want number with a letter.

Help

Comment: You want to generate random token ?

Comment: If you're planning on storing the data in a database then you should let the database generate to values.

Comment: I would put your token in a separate column and let the database auto generate the customer number. Then if you need to change the token it won't alter the primary key.

Comment: @Mary , may we have a little convo?

Comment: @Mary , [click](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169443/newwwww)

Comment: i want a token like A101 or something one letter and some numbers

Comment: @Mary can you show me how to do that ?

Comment: @jmcilhinney what do yo suggest me to do ?

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: i use ms-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to generate a random unique id , well, then , make use of the `Guid` class :

```
  Dim newId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString

  '''Or you can create required length integer

   Dim ran as New Random
   Dim newId as String = ran.Next(0, 9999999999).ToString("D10") '''this will generate a 10 digit unique ID
```

Now , note that you didn't mention if you want to store the data in some database , if you do, then the above codes may not be very useful as they might,at some point, generate same numbers....So here's a sql query to help you out :

```
  '''Must create a table with the following query :

   CREATE TABLE dbo.tblUsers
   (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   UniqueID AS 'UID' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)), 8) PERSISTED,
    Column2...........
    )
```

After creating such table , every time you `INSERT` a new data into the table, SQL will automatically generate a `UniqueID` for you

**Update**

Here's a solution that might generate an `ID` similar to `A1020`( the one that OP mentioned in the comment)

```
Public class abc()
Private Const allchars As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
Private Shared random As New Random()
Private sub GenerateId()

Dim builder = New StringBuilder()
For i = 0 To 5
    Dim c = allchars(random.[Next](0, allchars.Length))
    builder.Append(c)
Next
Dim NewId = builder.ToString()
End sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping .  i didn't thought about storing in database. I'll try your solutions.

Comment: @Ghosrtreturns , please mark the answer as answer if it helped :)

Comment: dim is not valid on a local constant declaration                                    Dim Const allchars As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"                               it suggests to delete "dim" , but if i delete dim .                                  
 Dim c = allchars(Random.[Next](0, allchars.Length))  reference to a nonshared  member requires object reference "random"

Comment: ow..sorry , make it a class level `private` variable

Comment: `Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        Const allchars As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
        Dim builder = New StringBuilder()
        For i = 0 To 5
            Dim c = allchars(Random.[Next(0, allchars.Length))
            builder.Append(c)
        Next
        Dim NewId = builder.ToString()

    End Sub` ***reference to a non-shared member requires object reference*** _random.[Next]_

Comment: ***Reference to a non-shared member requires object reference *** eror still exists @zack raian

Comment: @Ghosrtreturns , gimme a few minutes , i need to debug it

Comment: @Ghosrtreturns , strange, on my side , it works perfect

Comment: how to call that class in button click event ? @zack raiyan

Comment: keep these two lines in class level : `Private Const allchars As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"` , 
`Private Shared random As New Random()` and the rest of the code in the button click